# Change the fallback notification sound

Tags: notifications, sony-xperia-arc

Is it possible to change the fallback notification sound that is played when the active sound is not available?

I have a sound file I use for notifications on my SD card and every time I have the phone connected to a computer and the SD card is not available to the phone it plays an extremely annoying alternative notification sound.

I can not simply copy the file over the phone, the sound is only available for selection when I place it in the folder `Notifications` on the SD card, everywhere else it just doesn't show up.

The phone is a SE Xperia Arc.